# Let $F$ be a field. Is it true that if $[F(\sqrt{D}) : F] = 2$, then $D \in F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

In Dummit & Foote, problem 14.2.17(c), the authors hand us a quadratic extension of the form $F(\sqrt D)$. Now, while I am pretty sure you need that $D \in F$ to do this particular problem, I can't help but wonder if assuming this is even necessary. In other words, if the degree of the extension $F(\sqrt D)/F$ is $2$, then must $D$ belong to $F$?

My thoughts so far are as follows: If $D \not\in F$, then $[F(D) : F] > 1$. This puts $\sqrt D \in F(D)$, otherwise
$$
4 \le [F(\sqrt D) : F(D)][F(D):F] = [F(\sqrt D): F] = 2.
$$
This tells us that $F(D) = F(\sqrt D)$. My next observation was that if $\sqrt D$ has minimal polynomial $x^2 + ax + b$, we can write $\sqrt D$ in terms of $D$ and elements of $F$ and use this to find the minimal polynomial of $D$ over $F$:
$$
\sqrt D = -(D + b)/a, \ m_{D, F}(x) = x^2 + (2ab - a)x + b^2.
$$
Notice here that $a \neq 0$, or else $D \in F$!

Comment: I'm confused. If $D \not \in F$ then what does $F(\sqrt{D} )$ mean?

Comment: @Ethan You don't know what  $\,\Bbb Q(\sqrt{1+\sqrt 3})\,$ means?

Comment: @BillDubuque Now I'm no longer confused. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is false. Consider the case of $F=\Bbb{Q}$, $D=(1+\sqrt2)^2=3+2\sqrt2.$

We have $\sqrt{D}=\pm(1+\sqrt2)$, so $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt D)=\Bbb{Q}(D)=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$.

Answer (score 3):

If $[F(\sqrt D):F]=2$ the extension is Galois with group $\{1,\sigma\}$ and 
$$
\sigma(\sqrt D)=a+b\sqrt D,\qquad a,b\in F.
$$
Since $\sigma^2=1$ we must have
$\sqrt D=\sigma^2(\sqrt D)=a+ab+b^2\sqrt D$, i.e.
$$
a(b+1)=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad b^2=1.
$$
If $a=0$ and $b=-1$ it readily follows that $D\in F$.

On the other hand, if $a\neq0$ and $b=-1$ we have
$$
F\ni{\rm N}(\sqrt D)=\sqrt D\cdot\sigma(\sqrt D)=a\sqrt D-D
$$
from which $D={\rm N}(\sqrt D)-a\sqrt D\notin F$. Jyrki Lahtonen's answer shows an instance of the latter situation happening.

Comment: If $\operatorname{char} F = 2$, then $a+b\sqrt D\mapsto a-b\sqrt D$ is the trivial automorphism.

Comment: Ah! @JyrkiLahtonen is right; I mentioned near the end of my question that in the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt D$, $a \neq 0$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I fixed my answer.